# Where to store small information in a Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best way to store non-sensitive tiny pieces of information. For example i would like to save the last time the report was updated or maybe the maximum number of users connected at the same time, so nothing bigger then an integer or a string.

I am thinking:

- Saving them on a model but seems like an overkill to me.
- Saving them on a temp file?
- Creating a view cached partial that stores the value inside?

Is there any best practice for this kind of cases?

Comment: I prefer to create a model for it. This is nice because you can allow admins to edit the values if needed. I also like using the model as a singleton: https://github.com/stephencelis/acts_as_singleton

Comment: add t.timestamps to your migration for the updated at value.  I do that to all my models because you never know when you will need timestamps.  As far as the max number of users I think that it depends on your app structure.

Comment: Why would you even want to add max number of connected users on the Rails (app) level? That should be handled on the app server basis or by a load balancer. It just asking for a kick in the nuts by race conditions.

Comment: storing some real-time small data in Redis makes good sense to me

Comment: You're overthinking it. While a "RandomStats" model work? Yes! -> use it. Anything else just adds complexity.

Comment: @akz92 looks like a nice solution, however is it still up to date?

Comment: I used it recently on the latest release of Rails 4 without any problems, so I believe it is. Also, singletons are implemented by Ruby, this gem only makes it easier to use.